# What does something like int *array[99] = {0}, *u do?

Tags: c

```c
bool checkSubarraySum(int* nums, int numsSize, int k) {
    int i, s, found = 0;

    e_t buff[10000];
    int n;

    e_t *set[SZ] = { 0 }, *e;

    put(set, &buff[n ++], 0, -1);

    s = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < numsSize; i ++) {
        s += nums[i];
        if (k) s = s % k;
        e = lookup(set, s);
        if (e) {
            if (i - e->idx >= 2) {
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            put(set, &buff[n ++], s, i);
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

What is `e_t *set[SZ] = { 0 }, *e;` doing? `e_t` is a user defined type but I don't think that matters. `e` is not a pointer that has been defined anywhere in global scope to my knowledge, and I tried something like the following:

```
int *array[5] = {0}, *u;
```

and no syntax errors were given. The first part, i.e. `int *array[5] = {0}` initializes all five elements of this array to 0. But what is the purpose of `*u`? You can't just assign an array to something else, right, it's an address, not a pointer. And u has never even been defined, so, I would expect some sort of NameError...

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is similar to typing:

```
int x, y;
```

but notice the types when typing something like:

```
int a,  *b,  **c;
/*  ^    ^     ^
*  int  int*  int**
*/
```

therefore

```
int *array[5] = {0}, *u;
                   /* ^ is pointer to int */
```

Comment: So the star is tied to the variable name, not the type `int` or `bool` itself, right? So something like `int x, *y, z, **t` declares variables `x` and `z` of type int, `y` of type pointer to int, and `t` of type `int **` (pointer to pointer of int), right? That's why `*u` is not a pointer to a pointer of an int?

Answer (score 1):

```
int *array[5] = {0}, *u;
```

Is a declaration of two `int` objects. The first:

```
int *array[5] = {0}
```

declares an *array-of-pointers* to `int [5]` (meaning an array of 5 pointers to `int`) initialized to `NULL` by virtue of using the "*universal initializer*" `{0}`. The equivalent, but more intuitive initialization would be:

```
int *array[5] = {NULL}
```

The `','` is simply a separator here that allows the second declaration `*u` to be included in the same line without a separate `int *u;` declaration.

(not to be confused with the *comma-operator* that simply discards expressions to the left of the final `','` evaluating the last expression. See [What does the comma operator , do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do) -- thank you [@AnttiHaapala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918959/antti-haapala))

So:

```
..., *u;
```

declares a single (uninitialized) *pointer-to* `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
e_t *set[SZ] = { 0 }, *e;
```

is a *declaration* of two objects; `set` is an array of pointers to `e_t`, while `e` is a pointer to a single `e_t`.  It may also be written as:

```
e_t *set[SZ] = {0};
e_t *e;
```

Answer (score 0):

`e_t *set[SZ] = { 0 }, *e;` should be read as "the programmer hereby declares that the following are of type `e_t`: the objects *pointed to by* each `SZ` elements in `set`; **and** the object *pointed to by* `e`."

`= {0}` causes each element in `set` to be initialized to null pointers - the first explicitly and the remaining implicitly.